# SQL conn fail upon rating with POST and header(location)

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a rating system where the user is displayed one movie title at the time, then can rate the title "good", "bad", or "not seen". Then the script insert the movie id into a "has rated" table with the movie id and user id, and refreshes the page with a header('location') to itself.

The rating goes into the database, but the on the refreshed site, the script crashes and are not able to do the same sql-query to acquire the next movie title.

I use the array_diff function on two tables: 
- Movie title id
- Movie title id's user have already rated

The function returns an array of unrated movie title id's to variable 
    $notrated.

Then I set

```
  $nexttitle = $notrated[0];
```

Then I run:

```
$nexttitle = "";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE movid=$nextid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if(!$result) die("Trouble connecting to database");    
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
$nexttitle = $row['title'];}
```

Trouble connecting to database is triggered.

Comment: Add `mysqli_error($con);` to your code to view any possible error(s). Also, you reset the `$nexttitle`'s value to an empty string after assigning the `id`

Comment: What is `$nextid` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the problem!

The problem was this: I addressed the valid output with ass arrayName[0]. 
The array_diff function maintains the index number from the main array (first parameter), so when the loop goes on and the item index[0] is not valid, it gets thrown out of the array that array_diff generates. Thus there will not be an item at index[0] at one point. 
Resolved this by addressing valid output only if it was an existing key.